# Where Glimpse stores data?

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

Where Glimpse stores data shown in his tabs?
I find the data is got server-side, but I cannot identify the storage place for this the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glimpse stores the collected information in an [**in memory** persistence store](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/ApplicationPersistenceStore.cs) by default.

This in memory store keeps track of the last 25 requests that have been stored.

You can always replace this default persistence store with your own by implementing the [`IPersistenceStore` interface](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/IPersistenceStore.cs) and registering your own [IServiceLocator](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/IServiceLocator.cs) implementation that returns this alternate persistence store.

There is an example [here](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Replacing-Infrastructure) on how to do that for the default logger.